# Survival Analysis R Variance different from Greenwood formula?

Tags: r, survival

Hello I am learning about survival analysis and I noticed that the variance estimate from R's `survival` package is different from when I calculate variance by hand using green wood's formula

$$\widehat{Var}[\hat{S}(t)] = \hat{S}(t)^2 \sum_{t_i \leq t}\frac{d_i}{r_i(r_i - d_i)} $$

Where $r_i$ is the number at risk right before $t$ and $d_i$ is the number of deaths occurred at time $t_i$

```
library(survival)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
size = 10
deathtime <- seq(1, size)
death = rep(1, size)
df <- data.frame(deathtime, death)

surv.obj<- Surv(df$deathtime, df$death)

surv.fit <- survfit(surv.obj ~ 1)

df.fit <- tidy(surv.fit)


df.fit %>% 
  mutate(var.hand = estimate^2 * cumsum(n.event/(n.risk * (n.risk - n.event))), # Green Wood
         var.survival = std.error^2) #Survival Package
```

[image]

The var.hand calculated varies very differently then the variance calculated from the `survival` package I am curious why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std.err` reported by `survfit()` is the standard error of the *cumulative hazard*. From the help page for `survfit.object`:

> for a survival curve this contains standard error of the cumulative hazard or -log(survival)

That's just this part of the Greenwood formula:

$$ \sum_{t_i \leq t}\frac{d_i}{r_i(r_i - d_i)}.$$

You must multiply the corresponding variance of cumulative hazard by $\hat S(t)^2$ to get the variance in survival at time $t$.

```
survSquared <- seq(.9,0,-.1)^2
survSquared
 [1] 0.81 0.64 0.49 0.36 0.25 0.16 0.09 0.04 0.01 0.00
surv.fit <- survfit(surv.obj~1)
surv.fit$std.err
 [1] 0.1054 0.1581 0.2070 0.2582 0.3162 0.3873 0.4830 0.6325 0.9487    Inf
varCumSurv <- surv.fit$std.err^2
survSquared * varCumSurv
 [1] 0.009 0.016 0.021 0.024 0.025 0.024 0.021 0.016 0.009   NaN
```

Those values agree with yours.

Comment: I asked a follow up question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547650/survival-analysis-r-variances-difference-between-robust-variance-and-greenwoods @EdM thank you so much for answering my question the past couple weeks.